# Google Place Details android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am working with Google Places API.

My task is to type some name, example **Amazon** and it should return me the type of this place as **Shop**.

In short if I pass place name to some web service it should return me the type of that place.

I tried two solutions

**1)Place Autocomplete
I don't want to use this, because It returns so many results**

**2)Google Place Details API
Here I need to pass place ID instead of place name.**

So any one knows, How can I get Place details by passing it name to some web service.

Thank you

Comment: in google place api you have to pass place name and place type with browser key

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the combination of `Google Places API` and `Places Autocomplete API`.

`Places Autocomplete API` will provide `AutocompletePrediction` from there you can pick up the `placeId` that you will use with Google Places API to get the details of that place.

I know you said you don't want to use `Google Autocomplete API` but it can be configured to return a max number of results (default is 10 I think) and can be also configured to return certain types of places by adding `AutocompleteFilter`. This will limit the results and it will also return useful results for your case.